# Is this a general counterexample about Fubini's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $\chi$ be a smooth and null-average function with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$. The following iterated integral is well-defined
$$
\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}
f (x) \int_{- \infty}^x \chi (s) ds dx
$$
because the inner integral defines a function with compact support. But now, interchanging the order of integration one obtains
$$
\int_{s \in \mathbb{R}}
\left(\int_{s}^\infty f (x) dx \right) \chi (s) ds 
$$
and the inner integral, depending on $f$, may diverge.

*Question.* Am I missing something or is it a counterexample to the fact that if the hypotheses of Fubini's theorem are not satisfied things can go wrong? Looking on MSE I found a lot of complicated example to show this.

- The doubt comes from the fact that if I restrict the domain of integration (in the first equation) from $x\in \mathbb{R}$ to $x$ in the support of $\int_{- \infty}^x \chi (s) ds$ then everything works fine. It is like there is a loss of information in interchanging the order of integration.

Comment: wel for a start, what _are_ the hypotheses for the theorem?

Comment: What do you mean? I know that the situation doesn't fit the hypotheses of the theorem. The question is if there is some error that I don't see, or it shows that the hypotheses of Fubini, if not satisfied, can really bring to something that does not work.

Comment: then I have no idea what your question is...

Comment: Well, this is a different problem then. Maybe someone else will understand. But I added some lines to the question, hoping is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is such an example as you claim.
Of course you can find examples in any text that covers Fubini's theorem showing that the conclusion may  fail when one of the hypotheses fails.
Here, the hypothesis that fails would require $$\int_{\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x\big|f(x)\chi(s)\big|\;ds\;dx < +\infty .$$

Comment: What bugs me is that if one restricts from the very beginning the domain where $f$ is integrated (using that the test function is of compact support) then the three integrals (double and iterated) are all equals. What is strange to me is that not observing the compact support from the very beginning creates this phenomenon. Did I explain what I mean?

Comment: How to say, it seems like I am exploiting a bug in a computer program to show that something does not hold under weaker hypotheses.